# Why is an outside initialization of a variable not acceptable in a for loop?

Tags: for-loop, verilog, system-verilog

Initialization of a variable outside the `for` loop results in an error as `i` is not a task. But, if I initialize it within the `for` loop, it is running perfectly.

Why does the below code give an error as `i` is not a task?

```
module tb;
  int array[5];
  int i= 0;
  
  initial begin
    for (i; i<5;i=i+1) begin
      array[i] = i;
      $display("The values of array is array[%d] =  %d",i,array[i]);
    end 
  end
endmodule
```

below code works

```
module tb;
  int array[5];
  int i;
  
  initial begin
    for (i = 0; i<5;i=i+1) begin
      array[i] = i;
      $display("The values of array is %d",array[i]);
    end 
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3):

An initialization of a variable is not acceptable outside of a for loop because that is how the IEEE Std defines it.  If the *for_initialization* is present in the `for` loop, it must be of the form:

```
[optional_data_type] variable = expression
```

It is illegal to have the variable without the initialization expression.

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 12.7 *Loop statements* for the complete syntax definition.

Note that the *for_initialization* is optional.  For example, this is legal syntax:

```
module tb;
  int array[5];
  int i= 0;
  
  initial begin
    for (; i<5;i=i+1) begin
      array[i] = i;
      $display("The values of array is array[%d] =  %d",i,array[i]);
    end 
  end
endmodule
```